# How can i deserialize JSON object using jackson libraries in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I tried to read and convert objects from a JSON file to java objects using the jackson libraries. I tried both with the tree-model, and with JsonParser using JsonTokens, the problem is that the file contains an *ArrayList* and User has a parameter ("session") of type *GameSession*. My problem is that both methods fail to correctly recognize the start and end of *User* objects.

This is an example of the JSON file start, the session field can also be "null" :

```
[ {
  "username" : "Username0",
  "password" : "password",
  "session" : {
    "field1" : "secret",
    "field2" : null
  }
}, {
  "username" : "Username3",
  "password" : "password",
  "session" : null
}, {
...
},
...
]
```

This is my last attempt:

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

File file = new File(USER_PATH);

if (!file.exists()) return;

try {
    JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(file);
    parser.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());

    if (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        return;
    }

           

    synchronized (userDB) {
        while (parser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            User tmp = parser.readValueAs(User.class);
            userDB.add(tmp);
        }
    }
...
```

instead the with the tree-model I have problems already in this phase:

`JsonNode arrNode = objectMapper.readTree(file);`

I'd like to be able to understand how to handle the problem with both methods, so thanks in advance to anyone who will try to give me some clarification

Comment: Any reason you're not parsing directly to your DTO structure? `mapper.readValue` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

First define one or more classes with the same structure as the json data you want to read (with getters and setters):

```
public class Session {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    // TODO: also define getters and setters
}

public class UserData{
    
    private String username;
    
    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    private Session[] session;

    // etc...
}
```

Second, use ObjectMapper to deserialize:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
UserData[] data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, UserData[].class);
```